# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Unable to insert data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to save some data into my db after receiving it

Here's my api.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost:5432/****'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Communication(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comm'

    id = db.Column('comm_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    early = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    late = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    message = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

   def __init__(self, early, late, message):
        self.early = early
        self.late = late
        self.message = message


db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

@app.route('/api/form', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost', headers=['Content- Type', 'Authorization'])
def retrieve_info():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    else:
        early = request.json.get('early')
        late = request.json.get('late')
        message = request.json.get('message')

        test = Communication(early=early,
                                        late=late,
                                        message=message)

        db.session.add(test)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify('ok'), 200



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Here's the json that i send:

```
{
 "early": true ,
 "late": false ,
 "message": "Hello world" 
}
```

Weirdly i get 0 exception or error message, but nothing is saved on my db.
I don't understand what's wrong with my code (i checked the connection with the db is ok btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment, I think I see what you are trying to accomplish by defining a variable with your commit statement, but I prefer try/else to accomplish it. I'd probably refactor your code as below:

```
def retrieve_info():
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    try:
        early = request.json.get('early')
        late = request.json.get('late')
        message = request.json.get('message')

        test = Communication(early=early,
                             late=late,
                             message=message)

        db.session.add(test)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify('ok'), 200

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(e), 500
```

This way if there's an exception raised anywhere from instantiating your db model to committing the info to the db, the except portion will gracefully tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't [commit the session](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/) after adding the object.

Comment: Thanks, I added it but nothing changed

Comment: why did you define a variable with db.session.commit() ? I've never seen this. Did you try simply doing a commit without the variable?

Comment: Also, when you create the instance of your Communication model, where are you getting your two definitions: allow_early and allow_late? from what i can see in your code, it should just be: `test = Communication(early=early, late=late, message=message)`

Comment: Also perhaps worth pointing out, `db.drop_all()
db.create_all()` will wipe and re-init your database every time you start the application / run the file 'api.py'

Comment: OMG thank you @Chockomonkey the problem was the db.drop_all() that i forgot to delete ! you saved my day ( also i edited the errors of inattention, that you pointed out just above) thanks again